# Use URL argument to call an image into a page?

Tags: php, image, arguments

I have a basic CSS/HTML layout and I want to insert an image placeholder in the layout.  Then, users could call any image they wanted to appear in that spot. The image would be defined by an argument in  the URL.  For example, if someone went to...

```
/page.php?img=othersite.com/images/picture.png
```

I would want it to take `picture.png` and show it on the page on my site (the "`src`" part if the "`img`" tag would be a variable set by the `url=` section of the URL). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and all of the search terms I've though of turn up millions of unrelated results. Can anyone please start me in the right direction?

Comment: care to detail the steps of the user to perform such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it with:

```
<?php
   $url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'img', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
   $imageTag = "<img src='$url' />";
```

The filter would ensure you don't create XSS problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$image = $_GET['img'];
$imageTag = "<img src='$image' />";
?>
```

Then in the page, just echo `$imageTag` to display the image.

P.S. You should also validate the input for security.

Comment: Much thanks for your help (both answerers).  I'll have to research validation!